# Set parent div height to content that is not overflowing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider that's in place on my website.

The basic way that it works is depicted in this **jsfiddle** -

http://jsfiddle.net/6h7q9/15/

I've written code to set the parent's height to the height of the content div. This worked fine, until I introduced some content that did not have a fixed height and whose height might increase while it was being shown on the page. Is there a way, I can dynamically change the height of this parent div whenever content inside it increases or decreases it's height.

**HTML** -

```
<div id="slider_container">
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slide1">
        Has content that might increase the height of the div....
    </div>
    <div id="slide2">
        Has content that might increase the height of the div....
    </div>
    <div id="slide3">
        Has content that might increase the height of the div....
    </div>    
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Next" id="btnNext">
<input type="button" value="Previous" id="btnPrev">
<input type="button" value="Add text" id="btnAddText">
<div class="footer">
    I appear after the largest container, irrespective of which one is present....
</div>
```

**JavaScript** -

```
var currSlider = 1;
$('#btnNext').click(function(){
    debugger;
    var margin = $('#slider').css('margin-left');   
    if(parseInt(margin) <= -400) {
        return;
    }
    currSlider++;
    // Moving the slider
    $('#slider').css('margin-left', parseInt(margin) - 200 + 'px');    
    // Resetting the height...
    $('#slider').height($('#slide' + currSlider).height());
});
$('#btnPrev').click(function(){
    debugger;
    var margin = $('#slider').css('margin-left');
    if(parseInt(margin) >= 0) {
        return;
    }
    currSlider--;
    // Moving to the previous slider
    $('#slider').css('margin-left', parseInt(margin) + 200 + 'px');
    // Resetting the height...
    $('#slider').height($('#slide' + currSlider).height());

});
$('#btnAddText').click(function() {
    $('#slide' + currSlider).text('Hello World'.repeat(100));
});

String.prototype.repeat = function(times) {
   return (new Array(times + 1)).join(this);
};
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you would like the height of your div to be increased if it contains overflowing content to accommodate it?

Comment: What is wrong with using min-height instead of height in the CSS?

Comment: Do you want #slider to be the height of the active #slideX?

Comment: @CBauer - Yes, thats exactly what I want.

Comment: Just to point this out `height:auto` is default. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp you would never need to set it to auto unless you have some code preventing it from being the default value before hand if this is the case your test cases are useless as they did not show the sliders div's had any rules that effected the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this "answer" gets you going in the right direction. Since i don't have the time to fully look this up right now, i hope to send you in the right direction. if you do find out how to do this properly, please shoot me a message, since i would really like to know ^_^

- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#legacy-event-types

An example on how to use: (`DOMSubtreeModified` didn't work in IE from what i read. Therefor the `propertchange` event)

```
$('#slide1').on('DOMSubtreeModified propertychange', function() {
    console.log('test',this);
});
```

Another option is by using the MutationObserver:

- http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers
- https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers

---

### Updated 6-8-2014 15:00 CET

Since i totally misread the original post, this answer was useless to say the best. But since the problem is actually really easy to solve (or... at least i hope i understand the problem this time), i thought i'd post an answer that worked for the situation: a slider with content of different heights.

What was the problem with the original slider? You moved the content out of the container, which made it hidden. However, the container would still pick up the height of it, since it only had a fixed width. The fixed height on the '#slider' did not prevent the container of picking up the height from the '#slide-*'. Had you set the height for the container... all would be fine :-)

Here's the outline of the hidden slide, moved 'off canvas': http://i.gyazo.com/f2404e85263a7209907fdbc8f9d8e34e.png

I did not *fix* your fiddle by completing your code. I just rewrote it to provide you with an easier to maintain slider. Here's a fiddle with a working slider where you can add and remove stuff in the slides: http://jsfiddle.net/3JL2x/3/

Comment: I wish if this event was reliable. I've updated my answer with a process that worked for me, maybe it will be of use to you?

Comment: My answer was completely useless for the problem you ran in to :D So i felt a little guilty and went along to find out why it wouldn't resize again. it's actually pretty simple and i will update my post to reflect that :-)

Comment: @AbijeetPatro hope this solution is closer to what you needed. Just provided you with a new slider to fix your stuff :-) Less code, Less css, more awesome (i hope)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `height` properties in the .slide1, 2 and 3 and add `min-height` instead.
Like that :

```
#slider > div {
    min-height:200px;
    float:left;
    width : 200px;
}
#slide1 {  
    background-color : red;   
}
#slide2 { 
    background-color: green;    
}
#slide3 {    
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

**Live example**
http://jsfiddle.net/6h7q9/27/

Comment: only requires knowing the min height

Comment: So ? You need to make the block visible anyway so you'll need a height eventually

Comment: Problem is if the content is very less, the container won't shrink. Check my update.